# How to set a port to listen on udp instead of udp6?

Tags: centos, port, udp

I have an application that listen on udp port 1234. I already added the udp/1234 in my firewall and checked if the port is already added to the allowed ports. When I checked if the port is listening using netstat, the port is using udp6 instead of udp. Is there a way to change this to udp instead of udp6.
[please see image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JKkP.png). My Application is running in CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem. Try sending UDP to this service.

AF_INET6 address family also works for IPv4. With both the Linux network stack, and the presumably Java application given the process name you have listening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it is clear to me how this things work. I already tested my connection using nc and it worked.

Comment: This API compatibility seems unusual if you just know IPv6 is a separate protocol. But it is by design if you look at RFC 2553 and man 7 ipv6